# React-native-router-flux navigation clubbing drawer with bottomtab bar navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-native-navigation, react-native-router-flux, react-native-tabnavigator

Although there exists a lot of leads about react-native-router-flux and drawer navigation, i can't seem to figure out how do i club my existing bottomtab bar navigation with the side drawer.

Current routes that i have

```
      import React from 'react'
      import { Scene, Router, Actions, ActionConst } from 'react-native-router-flux'
      import LoginConnector from '../connectors/LoginConnector'
      import BottomTabbarConnector from '../connectors/BottomTabbarConnector'
      import Logout from '../layouts/login/Logout'
      import SelectionModal from '../layouts/login/SelectionModal'


      const scenes = Actions.create(
        <Scene key="root">
          <Scene key="login" component={LoginConnector} initial={true} hideNavBar/>
          <Scene key="selectionModal" component={SelectionModal} type={ActionConst.REPLACE} hideNavBar />
          <Scene key="logout" component={Logout} type={ActionConst.REPLACE} hideNavBar />
          <Scene key="bottomtabbar" component={BottomTabbarConnector} type={ActionConst.REPLACE} hideNavBar />
        </Scene>
      );
      export default () => (
        <Router scenes={scenes} />
      );
```

So whats happening is i load the login screen when the app starts, then on successful login i just call Actions.bottombar() which loads by Bottom Tab Bar which i have implemented using `TabNavigator` from `react-native-tab-navigator`
The tab switching works perfectly without any problems.

Now i want to add more screens and adding more tabs is not an option as i already have 5 tabs. So i want to implement the side drawer. And i am not able to figure out how do i configure my routes such that on successful login i continue to have the bottom tab bar intact in addition with the side drawer. The side drawer will have more screen navigation options on selection go to those respective screens I tried adding

```
 <Drawer
 type="static"
 content={<Menu closeDrawer={ () => this.drawer.close() }/>}
 openDrawerOffset={100}
 tweenHandler={Drawer.tweenPresets.parallax}
 tapToClose={true}
 ref={ (ref) => this.drawer = ref}
 >
 <Router>
           <Scene key="gallery" />
           <Scene key="logout" />
      </Scene>
 </Router>
</Drawer>
```

to my existing route but nothing happens. I have tried way too many things and failed.

Request for some help. Any help and pointers to solving this is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Vikram

Answer (score 1):

refer below code, in 'contentComponent' of Drawer you can design your own drawer with and pass to contentComponent as passed below. hope this code will help you.

```
import SideMenu from '../Component/SideMenu'

 <Router>
      <Stack>
           <Scene hideNavBar>
                <Scene initial>
                   <Scene
                    hideNavBar
                    key="mainApp"
                    drawerIcon={
                       <Icon
                       name="menu"
                       size={25}
                       color="white"
                       onPress={() => Actions.drawerOpen()}
                       />
                       }
                       drawer
                       contentComponent={SideMenu}
                       >
                          <Scene
                          initial
                          key="tab"
                          wrap={false}
                          tabBarPosition="bottom"
                          showLabel={false}
                          tabs
                          type={ActionConst.REPLACE}
                          tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: Constants.colors.themeColor }}
                          >
                              <Scene>...........</Scene>
                              <Scene>...........</Scene>
                              <Scene>...........</Scene>
                              <Scene>...........</Scene>
                              <Scene>...........</Scene>
                          </Scene>
                     </Scene>
               </Scene>
          </Stack>
   </Router>
```